# Emberjs - use @model hook data in component

Tags: ember.js

I have a route that grabs `posts` data from `mirage` like so:

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default class PostsRoute extends Route {
  async model() {
    return this.store.findAll('post');
  }
}
```

I can then do something like this

```
{{#each @model as |post idx|}}
   ..do stuff
{{/each}}
```

but let's say I want to rename `@model` to `foo` and use it in some other component - how can I do that?

Comment: do you mean to pass `@model` to a component and use it? If so, you can invoke a component and pass `@model` by the name of your choice and use it inside your component. Like 
```<MyComponeny @foo={{@model}} />``` and you can access `@foo` inside the component

Comment: Another option is to override `setupController` and you can name the property whatever you want. But yes as Gokul says, you can also rename when invoking a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first `@model` is a bit a "magic string" and always references to `this.model`.
what you can do is to define a getter on the `Controller`:

```
get foo() {
  return this.model;
}
```

Then you can use it as `{{this.foo}}` in your template.

Another way to reference `@model` as something else in your route template is to use `{{#let`:

```
{{#let @model as |foo|}}
  {{foo}}
{{/let}}
```

---

When you pass data to a component you can always rename it:

```
<MyComponent @foo={{@model}} />`
```

and then use `{{@foo}}` *inside* `components/my-component.hbs`.

Comment: I think {{@foo}} would have to be {{foo}} in your second example